# Transform GPS coordinates to a different projection in iOS app

Tags: ios, gps, gis

I need to pass user's GPS coordinates from the iOS app to the backend server. The iOS Location Services uses EPSG:4326 (also known as WGS 84) but the back end expect them in EPSG:900193

Does anyone have any information on how to transform the lat/long values to EPSG:900193 in the iOS app before sending them out?

My google fu is failing me. Searches didn't come up with anything I could use. Is there are formula, or a library that I can use?

Comment: it dawned on me why  your *goolge fu* was failing you.  EPSG:900193 is actually EPSG: *900913* as it's 1337 <sort of> for *google*  c.f., http://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/243/google-projection-900913/

Answer (score 0):

EPSG:900193 is also know as **Web Mercator**, which was originally called **Spherical Mercator**

Wikipedia has [a formula for conversion to Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator)

[The Google Maps / Bing Maps Spherical Mercator Projection](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/) has additional information, and as does [Conversion of British National Grid (WKID:27700) to WGS84(WKID:4326) and then to Web Mercator (WKID:3857)](https://osedok.wordpress.com/tag/web-mercator/)

The links will get you going, the last link has a javascript for conversion, which may, or may not suit your requirements.

Edit: Doing some light reading I found this interesting [Java code for WGS84 to Google map position and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661/java-code-for-wgs84-to-google-map-position-and-back)  and this gem http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/google-projection/

The biggest problem with all of the name changes...are they talking about the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at the [PROJ.4 Cartographic Projections](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library and its translations to many languages/platforms. For your particular case you may want to look at the [Changing Ellipsoid / Why can't I convert from WGS84 to Google Earth / Virtual Globe Mercator?](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/FAQ#ChangingEllipsoidWhycantIconvertfromWGS84toGoogleEarthVirtualGlobeMercator) FAQ